# How to update time in the timestamp column in oracle?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have bad data entries to be fixed where timein entered is greater than timeout e.g. 2014-12-01 13:15:00 as timein and 2014-12-01 01:32:00 as timeout. Actually the timeout should be 2014-12-01 13:32:00. How can I add or subtract 12 from the time portion of the timestamp data field in order to correct and update these values.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add 12 hours to the `timeout` whenever the `timeout` is greater than the `timein`, you can do something like

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET timeout  = timeout + interval '12' hour
 WHERE timeout > timein;
```

If that is not what you want to do in every case (maybe you want to add a day sometimes rather than 12 hours, maybe you want to adjust the `timein` instead, etc.) you'd need to be a bit more specific about the algorithm you want to implement.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you Justine. I have to change the logic though depending on the data I see. I needed a hint like you gave me. Thanks again.